# How to create a new column using IF else which has date filters (alternate to SAS then do)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I want to create a new column in Python dataFrame but my code is not working.

```
recession = 0
recovery = 0

if data['excl_flg'] == 0 and data['segment'] != 'ignore':
    if (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '2008-06-30'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 & (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '31Mar2010'.dt.to_period('M') >= 0:
         recession = 1
    elif (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '31Mar2010'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 and (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Sep2013'.dt.to_period('M')) >= 0:
        recovery = 1
```

[image]

This is my data , I am trying to create new column recession and recovery. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as i have understood (correct me if i am wrong), you want to update the recession and recovery column in the dataframe on the basis of difference between two dates.. FYI there are only 30 days in september:)

Comment: Yes,I want to add recession and recovery column in dataframe. Could you please have a look at my code and provide any solution if possible. (want to use if else statement only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. not using if else but serves the purpose..

## Data

```
   excl_flag        segment    vardate    obsdate
0          0         CC_620  2/29/2008  3/31/2008
1          1  CC_cur_It_660  2/28/2009  3/31/2009
2          0         ignore  2/28/2010  3/31/2010
3          0         CC_620  2/28/2011  3/31/2011
4          1         ignore  2/29/2012  3/31/2012
5          0         CC_620  2/28/2013  3/31/2013
6          1  CC_cur_It_660  2/28/2014  3/31/2014
7          0         CC_620  2/28/2015  3/31/2015
8          1  CC_cur_It_660  2/29/2016  3/31/2016
9          0         ignore  2/28/2017  3/31/2017
```

## necessary imports

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
```

#### coverting the dates to date format..

```
data['vardate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['vardate']).apply(lambda x: x.date())
data['obsdate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['obsdate']).apply(lambda x: x.date())

data['recession'] = 0
data['recovery'] = 0
```

#### implementing the conditions

```
data[((data['excl_flag'] == 0) & (data['segment'] != 'ignore'))].loc[(data['vardate']- datetime.strptime('2008-06-30',"%Y-%m-%d").date()).apply(lambda x: x.days < 0 )  & ((data['vardate'] - datetime.strptime('31Mar2010',"%d%b%Y").date()).apply(lambda x: x.days >=0)), 'recession'] = 1


data[((data['excl_flag'] == 0) & (data['segment'] != 'ignore'))].loc[(data['vardate']- datetime.strptime('31Mar2010',"%d%b%Y").date()).apply(lambda x: x.days < 0 )  & ((data['vardate'] - datetime.strptime('30Sep2013',"%d%b%Y").date()).apply(lambda x: x.days >=0)), 'recovery'] = 1

print(data)
```

#### your results are zero since the condition which you specified does not finds any takers

```
   excl_flag        segment     vardate     obsdate  recession  recovery
0          0         CC_620  2008-02-29  2008-03-31          0         0
1          1  CC_cur_It_660  2009-02-28  2009-03-31          0         0
2          0         ignore  2010-02-28  2010-03-31          0         0
3          0         CC_620  2011-02-28  2011-03-31          0         0
4          1         ignore  2012-02-29  2012-03-31          0         0
5          0         CC_620  2013-02-28  2013-03-31          0         0
6          1  CC_cur_It_660  2014-02-28  2014-03-31          0         0
7          0         CC_620  2015-02-28  2015-03-31          0         0
8          1  CC_cur_It_660  2016-02-29  2016-03-31          0         0
9          0         ignore  2017-02-28  2017-03-31          0         0
```

Comment: I applied same code on  my original data but it always give '0' for recession and recovery columns. i think is something i am missing.

Comment: please take a look at your conditions again, the date which you are taking (31Mar2010 & 30Sep2013) are giving zero result.. or please post some valid data so that i can look at that

Comment: Below SAS code gives desired results , at one point it gives 1 for recession but Python code gives 0 for all.   data data ;
 set data;
 if excl_flag=0 and strip(segment) ne "ignore" ;

 if intck("month",vardate,'30Jun2008'd)<0 and intck("month",vardate,'31Mar2010'd)>=0 then
  recession=1;
  else 
  recession=0;
  
 run;

Comment: Thanks for answering, Now i get desired results.

Comment: what changed. ?